# Is it possible to merge two records by using "delete from" statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some networked equipment that's attached to multiple networks/VLans (A, B & C), and other equipment that's just connected to one of the networks.  When I remove or replace a network, I need to update my database to reflect what the equipment is attached to so I'm trying to write a mysql statement to do that, but I'm running into various road blocks.

My table only has two fields and there cannot be duplicate records.  My data example is

```
deviceID network
1        A
1        B
1        C
2        B
2        C
3        A
4        A
5        B
```

How can I merge network A into network B so the above table would look like...

```
deviceID network
1        B
1        C
2        B
2        C
3        B
4        B
5        B
```

My initial attempt was to just `set network = 'B' where network = 'A'`, followed by a `DELETE network 'A'` statement but that would create duplicates, which isn't allowed for that table - even though the duplicates would be brief.  Using alternate methods, I just keep running into failed mysql statements by using `WHERE EXISTS` and various `FROM (SELECT)` statements.  Is it possible to do in a single mysql statement?  Do I need two?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `UPDATE IGNORE` with your update statement - this would skip any updates that caused duplicates. You would then follow this with a `DELETE` to clear the rows that had been skipped. For example:

```
UPDATE IGNORE mytable SET network = 'B' WHERE network = 'A';
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE network = 'A';
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html):

> With the `IGNORE` keyword, the update statement does not abort even if
>   errors occur during the update. Rows for which duplicate-key conflicts
>   occur are not updated. Rows for which columns are updated to values
>   that would cause data conversion errors are updated to the closest
>   valid values instead.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having two columns, you can consider make it three columns as
(the unique key remain unchanged)

- deviceID
- network
- status (1,0)

so, whenever a device has been removed / replaced,
you then mark the status to 0,
of course, to retrive the correct listing, `status=1` is required

Comment: I toyed with using this method, and I've used it in the past, but I was hoping to avoid it this time.  I didn't want to have to make modifications in my other pages/code to accommodate the new way of handling the new table structure.  Thanks for the response!